# Does running several Task.Run() or Task.Start() in a loop take care of the load-balancing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have a `List<Task>` (or `List<Action>` for Run() method) in a Console App. Say if I don't use the [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but I use the following code instead.

```
myTasks.ForEach (t => t.Start());
```

OR

```
myActions.ForEach(a => Task.Run(a));
```

Which one of the above will run the tasks in parallel. And is any or both of them going to take care of the load-balancing among the CPU cores transparently like [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does?

If the above code does the parallel work, Where would the [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) come in?

Comment: If you have tasks, then *by definition*, you're using the TPL.

Comment: @Luaan The majority of what you've just mentioned isn't applicable for a startable task.

Comment: all you're doing is using the `List` extension `ForEach` to perform an action on a collection.  I don't know why you'd expect any sophisticated load balancing from that.

Comment: @Jonesy Are you saying that Parallel.Invoke() would do the load-balancing but the code above wouldn't?

Comment: @Jonesy The started tasks would all run in parallel through the thread pool, which will balance the load optimally among the CPUs available.

Comment: @Luaan If the task wasn't created using the task constructor (which is true of most of your examples) then calling `Start` won't schedule the task; for all of those other things the task will have already been started, and calling `Start` will throw and do nothing else.

Comment: @Luaan, yes, after having the tasks all start working in parallel, it is possible for some of them to block until other tasks do some work, resulting in them logically ceasing to work in parallel for some portion of their work.  I considered that so obvious as to go without saying.

Comment: @Servy Hmm. Perhaps. Okay, let's just get rid of this conversation :)

Comment: @Luaan Agreed. I can't delete the question because it has an answer. I have added a close-vote.

Answer (score 2):

> Which one of the above will run the tasks in parallel?

`Task` doesn't have a `Run` method. It only has `Start` method for when you pass a delegate to `new Task`, which you shouldn't be using. Use `Task.Run` instead.

> And is any or both of them going to take care of the load-balancing among the CPU cores transparently

Both execute the given delegate on a thread pool thread, neither of them desides on which core they get executed. That is only managed by the underlying OS system.

Theres a [great article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff960958.aspx) which goes to lengths about concurrency:

> **The Worker ThreadPool:** Designed to provide services at the level of CPU parallelism, the worker ThreadPool takes advantage of multi-core architectures. There are two main considerations for CPU parallelism: dispatching work quickly and optimally; and throttling the degree of parallelism. For the former, the ThreadPool implementation makes use of strategies such as lock-free queues to avoid contention and work-stealing for load balancing.

Comment: So does TPL override the underlying OS behavior and do the magical load-balancing?

Comment: No. The TPL merely provides an abstraction over the threadpool, which is in charge of balancing work agains't the OS.

Comment: @fahadash It doesn't override the behavior.  It leverages tools provided by the OS, and expands upon them, to provide its behavior, which is what basically every single type in existence does.

Comment: Did I hear people say correctly that the TPL is redundant?

Comment: @fahadash No one said it was redundant. How did you understand that from what we said?

Comment: Well, if Task.Start() or Task.Run() static method schedule in Thread Pool and TPL leverages the Thread Pool. Then where does the TPL come in?

Comment: @fahadash It comes in as another level of indirection which provides things such as cooperative cancellation and provides the infrastructure for the `async-await` modifiers. Have you read about it at all?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I have. My question was strictly about load-balancing part. Does TPL do any special load-balancing that the above code Task.Run() doesn't?

Comment: @fahadash https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 Seriously, it's a single google search of "TPL" away. TPL is the whole batch, including the `Parallel` helper class and the ("low level") tasks themselves, as well as stuff like PLINQ and DataFlow. `Task.Run` is *part of TPL*. Perhaps you'd like to clarify what you mean by TPL, because it's obvious you don't actually mean *the* TPL.

Comment: @fahadash `Task.Run` **is a part of the TPL**, so asking if it does something that the TPL doesn't *when it is a part of the TPL* is a nonsensical question.

Comment: Ok. Looks like I may have misunderstood the concepts here. Sorry for making today a perfect Monday for you